# Oldstyle numbers with \scshape

Tags: fontspec

I would like to write `\textsc{abc 123}` and get small caps and oldstyle numbers with the current font. If I set

```
\defaultfontfeatures[\scshape]{RawFeature=+smcp,RawFeature=+onum}
```

I do get the small caps but not the oldstyle numbers. The same thing happens if I use `Numbers=OldStyle` instead of `RawFeature=+onum`.

But if I set

```
\renewfontfamily{\scshape}[RawFeature=+smcp,RawFeature=+onum]{anyfont.otf}
```

then it works! But I do not like the latter solution because if I use two fonts in a document (say Serif and Sans) I bound the `\scshape` command to one of them. The first command ought to work. But why does it fail? One may try any font supporting small caps and oldstyle numbers. Say, `GFSArtemisia.otf`.

Comment: Which font are you interested in?  There can’t be a general solution, because designers can define features differently.  Some provide special small-cap numbers.

Comment: GFSArtemisia.otf

Comment: Looks like a little bug in GFS Artemisia, because it works with, say, Minion Pro.  But why not just use `\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}[Numbers=OldStyle]`?  That works.

Comment: Your are right. It works with MinionPro. However it fails for many fonts. Another example of failure is cm-unicode. I wonder howto report this bug. Because people at GFS do not use TeX. It would be good if I could say something more that "it does not work". Solutions (as the one you suggest) are possible, for example \oldstylenums works for all (how does it work by the way? how is \oldstylenums defined?). The issue here is how to properly define \scshape to include oldstylenums.

Comment: `\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}[SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle}]` works.

Comment: For Artemisia, if you were to use `c2sc` rather than `smcp`, oldstyle numbers are defined as part of the feature.  (This is not true of all or even of most fonts.)

Comment: Problem solved! SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle} does the job. Thank you.

Comment: It works with cm-unicode as well!